# Discord.js V12 TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

While making a command for my bot i encounter error

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"
```

when using the command since the full code is kinda long and i don't want to include unnecessary details i think the issue is with this line

```js
client.users.cache.get(customer).send(`Your order has been claimed and will be delivered soon.`);
```

Because the command works normally when i remove that line but i'm not quite sure what's wrong with it, btw "customer" is defined at the start of the code with

```js
let customer = message.author.id
```

Comment: console this part `client.users.cache.get(customer)` if it is none, the issue exist here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'm quite confused as to why you're getting 2 different user objects, when you already have an existing one, being `message.author`.

If you didn't know, the `message.author` method returns a `User Object` of the creator of the message you're referring to, hence why creating another user object with the id of the message author object you already have makes no sense, in my opinion at least.

You can very simply do instead:

```
message.author.send('...')
```

That would message the original message creator a DM.
In addition, if this still happens to occur, please try console logging `message.author`, as your callback may be screwed up. I'd be happy to help on Discord (Bqre#0001) if this issue keeps happening - If and when you do, please first console log and be prepared with sending me the full error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user you're trying to send a message to is either uncached or doesn't exist, make sure "customer" is actually an ID or try to cache all users in the guild to see if that resolves it.

Comment: i replaced "customer" with "order.orderID" 
`client.users.cache.get(order.orderID).send(`Your order has been claimed and will be delivered soon.`);`
which yes already exists like this 

```// Update Status
        delete orderDB[ticketID];

        orderDB[ticketID] = {
         "orderID": order.orderID,
         "userID": order.userID,
         "guildID": order.guildID,
         "channelID": order.channelID,
         "order": order.order,
         "status": "Claimed",
         "ticketChannelMessageID": "not set",
         "chef": message.author.id
        };
```

Comment: You have to give it a User ID, so unless order.orderID is a Discord User ID, that won't work